# Are separate blocking-IO accesses to a file consistent at runtime without explicit syncing in Linux

Tags: linux, files, c, synchronization

I'm trying to figure out how often a sync or fsync operation really needs to be run in scenarios where power loss of concurrency isn't really a concern.  I'm looking for any guarantee the Linux kernel or Posix or glibc APIs might provide at runtime instead of the features provided by a particular filesystem.

If function a() opens a file, writes data to it, and closes that file, all with default blocking IO, is the file guaranteed to have that data for later calls to open on it without explicitly being synced to disk?  Does disk caching or the VFS layer guarantee that if function b() is called later to open that file name for reading, the same data will be visible as would be if a sync() of fsync() were called before the open?  Or should a sync always be called for data that's going to be read by a different chunk of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX guarantees that every `read` that occurs after a `write` is guaranteed to see the new data.  From [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> If a `read()` of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a `write()` of the data, it must reflect that `write()`, even if the calls are made by different processes. A similar requirement applies to multiple write operations to the same file position.

Calling `fsync` is not required.  Many, many programs on Linux and Unix require this for correctness and consistency, so failing to implement it correctly would be a serious defect.